# #include <QtWidgets>: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, make, qt5

Please don't crucify me. ChatGPT or Google did nothing, so here I am. Basically, I cannot use QtWidgets in my C++ code (for some reason).

The problem: When I include the  header in C++, I get this error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -Isrc/lib   -c src/ui/mainwindow.cpp -o bin/ui/mainwindow.o
src/ui/mainwindow.cpp:3:10: fatal error: QtWidgets: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <QtWidgets> //! doesn't work yet
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:34: bin/ui/mainwindow.o] Error 1
```

I tried re-installing the qtbase5-dev package from the Debian repositories. I tried Googling and asking ChatGPT. I modified the Makefile like so:

```
    # Makefile for Comet code editor

# Compiler
CC := g++
# Compiler flags
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/include/qt5
# Include directories
# INCLUDE := -Isrc -Isrc/lib  # Adjust include paths based on your project structure

# Directories
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := bin
BINDIR := bin

# Source files
SOURCES = src/main.cpp src/ui/mainwindow.cpp src/ui/mainwindow.hpp src/ui/mainwindow.css
# Object files
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
# Target executable
TARGET := $(BINDIR)/comet

# Default target
all: $(TARGET)

# Linking
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)

# Compiling source files
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@

# Run the comet executable
run: $(TARGET)
    ./$(TARGET)

# Cleaning
clean:
    rm -r $(BUILDDIR)

# Phony targets
.PHONY: all run clean
```

The code should render a basic window so far. But it doesn't. I asked on SO, got nothing but downvotes and answers "your makefile."

Comment: Your makefile.  Hint: `$(CFLAGS)` or `CXXFLAGS`?

Comment: Aside from the confusion between `CXXFLAGS` and `CFLAGS`, I don't actually see anything in the `CXXFLAGS` that would correctly locate the `<QtWidgets>` header. How exactly did you create the Makefile? IIRC the recommended way in the case of Qt is to *generate* the Makefile from a .pro [project file](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-notepad-example.html#project-file) using `qmake` - that should ensure that the correct platform-specific includepaths are used.

Comment: @MartinThornton will be sure to point out

Comment: @steeldriver I am using Clion - how do I generate a project?

Comment: @Renegade it looks like CLion supports Qt via cmake rather than via qmake directly - there's this [Qt projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html#cmake-qt) tutorial although unfortunately it is rather Windows-focussed.